# 2 dimensional non-linear recurrence $f(n,k) = \frac{f(n-1,k) + f(n-1,k-1)}{2} - \frac{\left(f(n-1,k) - f(n-1,k-1)\right)^2}{320}$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, dynamic-programming

$f(n,k) = \frac{f(n-1,k) + f(n-1,k-1)}{2} - \frac{\left(f(n-1,k) - f(n-1,k-1)\right)^2}{320}$,

with boundary conditions

$f(n,k) = 0$ $\;$ if $\;$ $n \leq k$,

$f(n,k) = 20n$ $\;$ if $\;$ $k = 0$.

While this is easy to solve programatically using recursion and memoization, I wonder

1. Is there a solution for this recurrence?
2. If not, is there an exact or approximate solution in the limit when $n\to \infty$ and $\frac{k}{n} \to \gamma \in [0,1]$?

Comment: An idea that might be useful: let $g(n,k) = f(n+k,k)$, then $$g(n,k) - g(n-1,k) = q(n,k) - \dfrac 1{80}q^2(n,k)$$ where $q(n,k) = \dfrac{g(n,k-1)-g(n-1,k)}2$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks! What is the direction to take after this. Generating functions?

Comment: Sorry, but that is all I gave because that is all I had. It seemed a somewhat simpler form, so I tossed it out in case you or someone else could find something more to do with it.